# docker compose command down and up does not create fresh image and container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have .net , sql database, kafka docker images and I used docker compose yml file to run them together.

I noticed the command down and up does not create fresh environment.

```
docker compose docker-compose -f dc-all-sql.yml down
```

then:

```
docker-compose -f dc-all-sql.yml up
```

I managed to have fresh environment by using docker desktop 'rest factory setting' option only.

Is my understanding of these command wrong?

Basically I want to have fresh environment, when I up the system, new docker images downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default, the only things removed by `down` are:
>
> ```
> Containers for services defined in the Compose file
> Networks defined in the networks section of the Compose file
> The default network, if one is used
> ```

so the images ar not removed , you could use this along with `down`:

> Options:
>
> ```
> --rmi type              Remove images. Type must be one of:
>                           'all': Remove all images used by any service.
>                           'local': Remove only images that don't have a
>                           custom tag set by the `image` field.
> ```

see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)

Comment: i see. my understanding of Containers and images is mixed up. so what should be the sequence? down then rmi? but after down, docker ps -a does not contains anything for me to remove.

Comment: or docker compose docker-compose -f dc-all-sql.yml --rmi all ??

Comment: what is the correct way and command in order to have fresh environment?

Comment: docker-compose -f dc-all-sql.yml down --rmi all && docker-compose -f dc-all-sql.yml up --build